# Find the tangents to the separatrices of the repellent equilibrium point $x_0$ of the Newton equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the tangents to the separatrices of the repellent equilibrium point $x_0$ of the Newton equation:

$$\ddot x=-\frac{d}{dx}U(x),\\ U^\prime (x_0)=0,\\  U^{\prime \prime }(x_0)<0$$

in the phase plane $(x,\dot x)$

Can anybody help me please? Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks.